# Choosing ES5 classes or functions on writting a javascript fronted library

Tags: javascript, function, class, ecmascript-5

I am writting a javascript tool for image manipulation and cropping. I've started writting it using ES5 classes and some ES6 syntax.

Looking for inspiration I decided to analyse the code of d3 library, because I look up to Mike Bostok, its developer. And I realized he uses no classes, but funcions, but using some ES5 syntax like import modules.

Is there any technical reason, other than the personal preference, to choose one or another approach?

Comment: You are confusing versions of EcmaScript. ES6 has `class` syntax (and modules), ES5 has function constructors. They are the same thing: the `class` syntax de-sugars to functions. So it is a matter of personal preference which one you use. I would say that using the `class` syntax makes your code more approachable and clear to a reader.

Comment: some browsers do not implement ES6 yet

Comment: @sdgluck Thanks. Maybe I was wrong about the fact `class` syntax belongs to ES5. The thing is I read, I don't remember where, something about the performance of the instantiating new classes with `new`. But, after all, the `new` operator it's no more that a call to the constructor method. I'm going with ES6 classes. Thank you again.

Comment: @thiagoh I know. I always transpile my code with babel and webpack.

Answer (score -1):

manelio. I'm not a guru, but I think you should use transpilers, more specific, some IDE or code editor. I use (and I recommend) [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com) and Typescript. It works perfect, plus it's totaly configurable. This tool allows you choose target compilers (ES5 or ES6), which module code generation use such as system, commonjs, amd, umd, es6 or es2015, might be things of your interest.
It'll depend on your target clients. If you want compatibility or using latest features of ecmascript for your productivity.